# How can I make omelettes look better?

Tags: omelette

I'm working on a sort of high protein+carbohydrate omelette that I can prepare in batch, dump into containers, and take with me when I'm on the go.

I've devised a sweet potato + egg recipe that goes something like this:

1. Boil sweet potatoes
2. Peel sweet potatoes
3. Put sweet potatoes in blender with eggs
4. Blend
5. Dump into pan, cook while stirring

So far so good.  Here's the problem:  The sweet potatoes and eggs both turn brown, giving the end result an unappealing look.

Is there a way to alter the recipe so that it is aesthetically more pleasing?

Comment: White sweet potatoes?

Comment: @Catija What's the difference between a white sweet potato and a normal potato?

Comment: Sweet potatoes (regardless of color) aren't the same plant as regular potatoes (regardless of color). They're in different families *Convolvulaceae* vs *Solanaceae*.

Comment: Have you checked a Spanish omelette recipe?

Comment: White (sometimes "yellow") sweet potatoes, as opposed to the typical orange yam "sweet potato" are often harder to find, but well worth it IMHO on a flavor basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like this is more like scrambled eggs instead of an omelet. It does sound tasty, but I can understand your issue with the coloration.

If you're using orange sweet potatoes, that is likely the biggest cause of the coloration issues. Eggs themselves usually stay yellow when cooked, though they may turn brown if cooked and then left to cool and wait around for a while. (I don't normally do that, so I can't really say.) I have a couple possible solutions:

1) As Catija suggests, you can try using white sweet potatoes. They have a similar flavor, though a somewhat different nutritional profile. Still very good for you.

2) Try shredding the potatoes instead of blending them with the eggs. This is probably the solution I would try first. Shredding will avoid mixing the colors to the extent that blending does, and still allows the potato to spread throughout the omelet/scramble. If you do this, I would shred the potato first (peel if you want, though the peel has a lot of nutrients in it), cook the shreds (options: baking, sauteing in a little oil or butter, or microwaving - you can try boiling, but it would be more like parboiling as the shreds would only need a minute or two in the water to cook). Then you can just stir the shreds in with the eggs (no blending) and cook.

3) Slice the potatoes, cook (can cook in the same manner as the shreds, though times will obviously differ), cook the eggs like you would a traditional omelet and layer the egg with the potatoes in your dish.

Here are a couple resources discussing the different type of sweet potatoes available so you can figure out what would work best for your purpose:

http://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-between-yams-and-sweet-potatoes-word-of-mouth-211176

Paleo/Primal site (I'm not Paleo, but the site has good images of the different types of sweet potatoes): http://www.marksdailyapple.com/difference-yams-sweet-potatoes/

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately shredding isn't an option as that would exceed the time budget allocated for this dish..  I could try option 3, i.e. just adding the sweet potatoes separately.  Ideally I want to be able to blend a bunch of stuff together and cook it all, as it's easier to scale up to make 4 or 6 breakfasts in one go.

Comment: I occasionally forget about mine, but I use my food processor fitted with a shredding disk to shred in seconds... do you have this option at all? Same goes for slicing.

Comment: @Catija Ahh, I didn't know they made those.  Thanks for that! :)

Comment: Yeah, food processors often come with a shredding and/or slicing disk, so that would cut down on the time quite a bit. If time's really a factor, that's what I'd go for. Or you could boil/bake the sweet potatoes and cut them up and add them to the eggs, instead of blending them. That might work.

Comment: Hello Duncan, health and nutrition is off topic here. I removed the link about that part. +1 for the rest of the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is trying to put the sweet potatoes through the belnder.

Instead, follow the preparation for the spanish Tortilla de Patatas, or a slight shortcut, and avoid flipping it by cooking it like a fritata:

1. Cook the potatoes in slices, (frying is typical, but you can also roast them).
2. While the potatoes are frying, mix up the eggs & pre-heat the broiler of your oven.
3. Put the hot potatoes in with the eggs and a healthy pinch of salt.
4. Pour the mixture into a hot broiler-safe pan (with a little bit of oil in it)
5. Spread the potatoes so they're not sticking out too much.
6. Once the bottom is set, place it under the broiler to cook through and brown the top.

Once it's cooked, you can let it cool, and slice into wedges of an appropriate portion size, wrap them up, and store in the fridge for a couple of days.

Answer (score -1):

How about blending the potatoes with only half of the eggs?  If you are maxing a scramble you can pour one in first, wait for it to coagulate a little, and then add the rest.  If you are making an omelette you pour the eggs sans potato first, wait for it to harden, and then pour the sweet potato eggs on top.